# How to serve an application in 2 different domains

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs application where I want to show few selected pages in one domain and not show them from another domain. For example I want to show /about in something.com and hide it from somethingelse.com . Im using nextjs 13 and page components for routing. And we are using nx for monorepo. Basically we need to create a landing on another domain, but with functionality from the main app, like logging in.

Comment: what problems are you facing? You've said what what you want to do, but haven't said much else

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for middleware. With this you can check for certain host and path names, then redirect the user appropriately.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

For example, you can redirect any path beginning with `/about` to `/home`:

```
// src/middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
}
 
// These are the paths your middleware runs for
export const config = {
  matcher: '/about/:path*',
}
```

Comment: I do not need redirects, just serve route on domain B and all others on domain A

Comment: Because you are using Next JS which creates pages/routes for you based on file structure, its not possible, at least from my own understanding.  Instead you will have to redirect users away from those routes, either through gssp, middleware or the next config redirect stuff.

Comment: Either way, the answer is middleware. for your case you should probably use rewrite. just look at the documentation and come back to us if you have trouble.